# How do I make it so that I can use javascript to display a variable on HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a chrome extension that finds the url of the active website you are on, how do I make it show on popup.html?

```
import { getActiveTabURL } from "./utils.js";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  const activeTab = await getActiveTabURL();
  const url = activeTab;
  if (activeTab.url) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get((data) => {
      console.log("History: ",url);
      const container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
      container.innerHTML = 'History:',activeTab;
    })
  }
});
```

right now when it switches the innerHTML in the popup, only the words"History:" appear, and the variable "url" doesnt how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you mean to concatenate the value? `container.innerHTML = 'History: ' + activeTab;`

Comment: Did you check the response you are getting from the `getActiveTabURL` ? As you are importing it.

Comment: Here you declare ```const url = activeTab;``` so call it ```container.innerHTML = 'History:' + url ;```. But I'm confuse with this ```if (activeTab.url){ }```